# NetCDF: NoSuchFieldError: pdsHash when opening a file

Tags: java, scala, netcdf, grib

I am trying to open grib2 file with NetcdfDataset.openDataset()

```
val path= getClass.getResource("/grib2/weather.grib2").getPath
val gribFile = NetcdfDataset.openDataset(path)
```

and I met with `NoSuchFieldError: pdsHash`. Does it mean that this file is invalid? If not then how to open it?

Comment: which version of `netcdf-java` version are you using?

Comment: I am using 4.5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to install `netcdfAll` instead `netcdf-java`.

```
  "edu.ucar" % "netcdfAll" % "4.6.3"
```